# Create a list of all possible paths in a graph given a starting and ending point

Tags: python, class, graph, path, breadth-first-search

Given the following Graph class which takes a graph object and outputs it's adjacency list:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self, graph_str):
    self.graph_str = []
    graph_str = graph_str.splitlines()
    for i in graph_str:
        i = (i.split())
        self.graph_str.append(i)
    directed_helper = self.graph_str[0]
    directed_score = directed_helper[0]
    weighted_helper = self.graph_str[0]
    weighted_score = weighted_helper[1]
    self.weighted = weighted_score
    self.directed = directed_score
    self.graph_str.pop(0)
    if self.directed == ("D"):
        self.directed = True
    elif self.directed == ("U"):
        self.directed = False
    if self.weighted == ("W"):
        self.weighted = True
    elif self.weighted != ("W"):
        self.weighted = False
    if self.weighted == False:
        self.edge_number = graph_str[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[2]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]  
    elif self.weighted == True:
        self.edge_number = graph_str[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[4]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]             
    if self.weighted == False:
        if self.directed == True:
            for s in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = s[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = s[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, None))
        elif self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, None))
                self.adjacency_list[self.second_element].append((self.first_element, None))
    elif self.weighted == True:
        if self.directed == True:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.third_element = t[2]
                self.third_element = int(self.third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, self.third_element))
        if self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.third_element = t[2]
                self.third_element = int(self.third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, self.third_element))
                self.adjacency_list[self.second_element].append((self.first_element, self.third_element))
    (self.adjacency_list)
```

And the following function which performs a breadth first search on the same graph object:

```
def bfs_tree(graph, start):
graph = Graph(graph_str)
parent_array = []
found_parent = []
empty_list = []
for _ in graph.adjacency_list:
    parent_array.append(None)
    found_parent.append(False)
empty_list. append(start)
found_parent[start] = True
while len(empty_list) != 0:
    element = empty_list.pop()
    for i in graph.adjacency_list[element]:
        if found_parent[i[0]] == False:
            found_parent[i[0]] = True
            parent_array[i[0]] = element
            empty_list.insert(0, i[0])
return parent_array
```

I wish to Use backtracking to write a function allpaths(graph, source, destination) that takes a graph object, a source vertex (integer), and a destination vertex (integer), and returns a list of all possible paths from the source vertex to the destination vertex that do not contain any cycle. A path is list of vertices where the first element is the source vertex, the last element is the destination vertex, and the elements in between (if any) are vertices along the path.

For example:

```
# triangle graph
graph_str = """\
U 3
0 1
1 2
2 0
"""

print(sorted(allpaths(Graph(graph_str), 0, 2)))
```

which should output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2]]
```

and this:

```
graph_str = """\
U 5
0 2
1 2
3 2
4 2
1 4
"""

print(sorted(allpaths(Graph(graph_str), 0, 1)))
```

which should output:

```
[[0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 4, 1]]
```

So far I have:

```
def allpaths (graph, source, destination):
    graph = Graph(graph_str)
    parents = bfs_tree(graph, 0)
    counter = 0
    array_a = []
    array_a_2 = []
    for i in parents:
        if len(parents) >= counter:
            if parents[counter] == source:
                if len(parents) > counter+1:
                    a = counter
                else:
                    a = (counter)
            else:
                counter+=1
    for a in parents[counter:]:
        array_a.append(a)
    for c in parents:
        if destination not in parents and parents[0] != None:
            if c not in array_a:
                array_a.append(c)
    array_a.append(destination)
    if None in array_a:
        array_a.remove(None)
    for b in array_a:
        if b not in array_a_2:
            array_a_2.append(b)
    return (array_a_2)
```

Which only outputs one path, not all, and I am unsure how to continue with this.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated :)

Comment: "Any help would be much appreciated" is far too broad for Stack Overflow. If you're looking for people to collaborate with on this task, consider asking people in person. If you have questions about specific stumbling blocks, ask specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to write this algorithm yourself? I am only asking because it looks like what you are looking for is the all_simple_paths function in the wonderful graph library networkx.

Comment: Unfortunately yes I am looking to write this algorithm myself, but thank you very much for the advice regardless :)